# In-app purchases in iOS webapp?

Tags: ios, web-applications, in-app-purchase, iphone-standalone-web-app, iphone-web-app

This might be a stupid question but after googling for a bit I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Is there any way of allowing users to buy things with their Apple ID in a webapp? I know it's basically a website loaded into a stripped down Safari but I wanted to be sure.

I'm developing a game that runs in a simple Android app with webview but on iOS I use the webapp function because Apple does not allow an app to simply load a website. Would it be possible to offer in-app purchases through an iOS webapp?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your setup but I don't think it will matter.
If your app is packaged into a native iOS app (even if you're loading some HTML), you will be able to offer in-app purchases but it will require you to write some objective-c native iOS code.

If your app is not packaged into a native iOS app, then no, you can't offer in-app purchases.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. You 'add' the app by using the 'add to homescreen' option in safari, so it's not a native app. Because Apple was so positive about webbapps back when the iPhone was introduced I hoped they would have some way to enable this. Shame.

Comment: You can package your app into a native app if you want but you'll need to explore your different options (Phonegaps of the world...).